# How to get the value of text area(tinymce) using jQuery in Moodle?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, editor, moodle

How to get the value of `text area(tinymce)` using **jQuery** in **Moodle**
My text area code is:

```
$editor = \editors_get_preferred_editor();
$editor->use_editor("ans");
echo \html_writer::tag('textarea', '',
    array('id' => "ans", 'name' => "ans", 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 5));
```

My **jQuery** code to get the `value of editor` field is:

```
 var answer = $("#ans").val();
```

But this code is not working, gives nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tinymce api:

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());


// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});


// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent();
```

Before this code check which editor user use (check if tinyMCE is null, try-catch etc.)